# How to retrieve data from a complex data structure in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Data:

Is there any way to access all of these "lineText" fields from the collection in MongoDB through a single query?

Comment: Can you post a sample data? just the data not an image

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OBoEUeOTvzpQk2m8h8-mRRDpxM8GQR6v/view?usp=sharing drive link

Comment: And which shape do you want the `lineText` to be? I mean as a single array of values or something?

Comment: You can start from here [Array Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-array/index.html). You can also do a internet search for "query nested arrays in MongoDB".

Comment: @prasad_ i don't think so the nested query operators work in my case

Comment: @DheemanthBhat basically I want to access all the lineText fields from the collection and append them into a single string.

Comment: You can include a sample output you are expecting (and any process associated with it) in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$text" },
    { $unwind: "$text.paragraphs" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            result: {
                $push: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$text.paragraphs.lineText", 0]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$result",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: { "$concat": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Wow, work like a charm, thanks, Dheemanth Bhat.

Comment: I am not sure about the performance. Seems like huge amount of data. Think of performance as well.

Comment: it is working fine, basically, I just want to use it once on my DB for getting data from old documents.